# Should Garry's Mod Gamemodes have separate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

In the Half Life 2 mod-turned-developed Valve game Garry's Mod, there are dozens, if not hundreds, of separate gamemodes, and to make things even more confusing, each server can have different modifications to those gamemodes. Because just tagging questions "garrys-mod" still leaves such a wide range of ambiguity (eg: hitbox issues in UCH, damage reduction of Kevlar in TTT, strength of barricade materials in Zombie Survival), should some of the more popular Garry's Mod gamemodes get their own tags (not all gamemodes require one, because of how many there are)?

Comment: Do you have any question that you think would benefit from more specific tagging? No need to implement solutions for problems that aren't there.

Comment: @Raven Well, one idea might be that a TTT player wouldn't be able to help with ZS questions, but would still see them all in their favorite tags. Also, grenades/remote detonation packs/suicide bombs function differently and are collected in different ways in TTT and ZS, and points are gained thru different means.

Comment: My apologies, I was unclear; what I meant was - which questions *currently on the main site* would benefit from more specific tagging? Admittedly, there are only ~30 of them in the first place (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garrys-mod)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

This level of sub-tagging is not necessary. There are only very few games which have been tagged with additional detail, and these games (for example, [TF2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) - 427, [Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) - 2545, [Diablo 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) - 1997, [Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) - 2502,) have hundreds of questions each.

**A game with so few (27) tagged questions does not need a set of sub-tags.**